# Convert UTF-8 files to ANSI

Tags: c#

How to remove `NUL` string in the message box

```
System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\VQ\NQCUEMES221222122249.txt");
byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fs.Length);
fs.Close();
System.Text.Encoding inputEnc = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
System.Text.Encoding outputEnc = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
//System.Text.Encoding outputEnc = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
//System.Text.Encoding outputEnc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
//System.Text.Encoding outputEnc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
byte[] decoded = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(inputEnc, outputEnc, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
System.IO.FileStream fw = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\VQ\NQCUEMES221222122249_NEW.txt");
fw.Write(decoded, 0, (int)decoded.Length);
fw.Close();
MessageBox.Show("END");
```

The correct conversion instead is done by NOTEPAD++

With NUL:
[image: With NUL]

Without NUL:
[image: Without NUL]

Comment: Are these NUL characters already present in the input file?

Comment: Are you really sure you need to make the conversion? Where are you seeing the problem you're trying to fix? May be there's a better way!

Comment: The chances are that this is not an encoding issue? It looks looks like something is writing  null (0x00) instead of spaces 0x32.

Comment: As a side note. The only character in UTF-8 that will ever result in a zero value (0x00) being seen in the encoded text is from the NUL character and this isn't even unique to UTF-8 and exists in other non-unicode encodings including ASCII.

Comment: A: there is no "correct" translation from utf8 to ANSI, because ANSI isn't a single thing - it is a wide range of possible code-pages, and you haven't told us which (and which characters are available depends on which), and B: Encoding.Default *doesn't mean ANSI* - it is largely undefined; on recent .NET versions, it means UTF8 again!

Comment: @phuzi , a UTF-16 encoding interpreted as ASCII has `0` as every other byte.

Comment: @strom they said utf8, and even for utf16 that statement only applies for single-byte code-points (I will grant that in English text, single-byte code-points dominate)

Comment: @Strom I only said UTF-8 which has variable length charachters, this is definitely not true of the UTF-16, UTF-32 encoding schemes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input files has NUL characters you could replace them by spaces after reading the input file using:

```
for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    if (bytes[i] == '\0')
        bytes[i] = ' ';
}
```